# Opam says upgrade is not possible

Tags: ocaml, opam

In particular, 'opam upgrade' produces this message:

"Upgrade is not possible because of conflicts or packages that are no longer available:
  - Conflicting query for package camlp4.4.02.1+system"

1) How might I get out of this situation?

2) How might I avoid having this happen again?

My opam is 1.2.2, and ocaml is 4.02.1.  OS is linux mint (ubuntu derivative)

Comment: is aspcud installed?

Comment: It wasn't.  I installed it and ran 'opam upgrade' again.  I worked out a quite complicated plan that reported success.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that there is some inconsistency in OCaml repository currently. Probably the situation you've got is not your fault at all. To resolve the issue you can try to manually remove or upgrade the conflicting package. Other approach would be just to start from scratch, i.e., to delete your switch and install all the needed packages again.

Comment: @LucasMembrane  switch is like which compiler and associated libraries are being used. type `opam switch` and you'll see what you're currently using.